# Capture group on (possibly empty) string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

If I have a string and wish to capture a possibly empty string (and subsequently check if indeed it was empty) how can I do this? My regular expression works when the captured section is not empty and on first impressions it might seem to work in case the string is empty since `Console.WriteLine(second);` produces no output.

```
string notEmpty = "abc|CaptureMeButICanBeEmpty|def";
string isEmpty = "abc||def";
string regEx = @"^\w+\|([^|]+|)\|\w+$";
var match = Regex.Match(notEmpty, regEx);
var match2 = Regex.Match(isEmpty, regEx);

string first = match.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(first); // CaptureMeButICanBeEmpty
string second = match2.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(second); // No Output

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups.Count); // 2
Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups.Count); // 2
```

However, it is impossible to know if `second` is empty **because** the capture group was empty or simply because there was no second capture group at all.
That is to say:

```
string third = match2.Groups[2].Value;
Console.WriteLine(second); // No Output
```

also produces no output, since the capture group is non-existent, and testing with something like

```
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(second));
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(third))
```

does not work either as both return true (I expected perhaps `string.IsNullOrEmpty(second)` to return true but `string.IsNullOrEmpty(third)` to throw an index out of bounds exception or something similar.

I realise I can use the result of `match.Groups.Count` to determine how many capture groups there should be in the sample code [note: C# defines Groups[0] as the entire match] but I do not want to have to rely on this.

Comment: Why not simply capture stuff before and after, then drop both from the string giving you the resulting middle 'group' as a string?

Comment: I think you need an optional group, `@"^\w+\|([^|]+)?\|\w+$"`, and then check if a Group matched by accessing the `.Success` property of the match, see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/RbwTdg). When `match2.Groups[1].Success` is false, you know Group 2 value is empty.

Comment: Do yo need regex? Would it be feasible to just use `string.Split` instead?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks - I see what you mean about optional group. Think you meant to perform a check to see if `Success` property is true and then get the value instead of printing the bool but I get the gist. However this could still be done by first accessing `match.Groups.Count` to obtain the number of groups and indexing the `Groups` property that way, which is kindda what I wanted to avoid. Maybe there isn't a super _clean_ way to do it though.
@JonasH In this example code yes but real code is a very long pipe-deliniated string with many (possibly empty) capture groups so not so pretty

Comment: To know whether there was a capture group in the string (for example, there isn't in `"abcdef"`) then use `@"^\w+(\|[^|]*\|)?\w+$"` and `Groups[1].Success` will only be `True` if there is a capture group, whether empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to check group count is wrong because the number of groups is set by (or in) the regex pattern: the number of groups is always the amount of capturing groups + 1 (for the whole match). So, if you check `match.Groups.Count` it will always give you `2` because `^\w+\|([^|]+|)\|\w+$` contains a single capturing group.

Now, it is not possible to use an optional pattern inside an obligaotry capturing group to check if a group matched or not, because the group value will be initialized with an empty string regardless, and the group `.Success` property will then be set to `true`.

The only way out here is to make the *capturing group* pattern optional and then check the match group `Success` property, and if it is `true`, get the string value of the group, else, assign the default value of your choice.

Here is a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/QIE9CC):

```cs
string notEmpty = "abc|CaptureMeButICanBeEmpty|def";
string isEmpty = "abc||def";
string regEx = @"^\w+\|([^|]+)?\|\w+$";
var match = Regex.Match(notEmpty, regEx);
var match2 = Regex.Match(isEmpty, regEx);
 
var first = match.Groups[1].Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : "No ouptut";
Console.WriteLine(first); // => CaptureMeButICanBeEmpty
var second = match2.Groups[1].Success ? match2.Groups[1].Value : "No ouptut";
Console.WriteLine(second.ToString()); // => No Output
```

Well, you may actually perform any actions you need if you use an `if` block after checking `.Success` property.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense but what you say about the `.Sucess` property always being true for a non-optional capture group (even when the string is empty) doesn't seem to be true when I run the code. I realise now why my original Regex always did but if you change `([^|]+|)` to `([^|]+)` it seems to work even without being an optional capture group. i.e [this demo code](https://ideone.com/t8ZAEw) achives the same result. Althought your solution makes the intention clearer and surely is better practise

Comment: @amy `^\w+\|([^|]+)\|\w+$` does not find any match in the `abc||def` string. The Group 1 is false because the whole match failed. See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/P48OHw).